# leaflet, Error: cannot allocate vector of size 177.2 Mb

Tags: r, memory, leaflet

I have tried everything I can think of to fix this error but I have not been able to figure it out. 32 bit machine, trying to build a choropleth. The data file is pretty basic some municipal IDs with population figures associated with it. The shape file is taken from here: www.ontario.ca/data/municipal-boundaries

```
library('tmap')
library('leaflet')
library('magrittr')
library('rio')
library('plyr')
library('scales')
library('htmlwidgets')
library('tmaptools')
setwd("C:/Users/rdhasa/desktop")
datafile <- "shapefiles2/Population - 2014.csv"
Pop2014 <- rio::import(datafile)
Pop2014$Population <- as.factor(Pop2014$Population)
str(Pop2014)
```

'data.frame':   454 obs. of  9 variables:
 $ MUNID       : int  20002 18000 18013 18001 18005 18017 18009 18039 18020 18029 ...
 $ YEAR        : int  2015 2015 2015 2015 2015 2015 2015 2015 2015 2015 ...
 $ MAH CODE    : int  1106 10000 10101 10102 10401 10402 10404 10601 10602 10603 ...
 $ V4          : int  1999 1800 1813 1801 1805 1817 1809 1839 1820 1829 ...
 $ Municipality: chr  "Toronto C" "Durham R" "Oshawa C" "Pickering C" ...
 $ Tier        : chr  "ST" "UT" "LT" "LT" ...
 $ A           : int  11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 ...
 $ B           : chr  "a" "a" "a" "a" ...
 $ Population  : Factor w/ 438 levels "-","1,006","1,026",..: 160 359 117 432 86 419 97 73 179 171 ...

```
mnshape <- "shapefiles2/MUNICIPAL_BOUNDARY_LOWER_AND_SINGLE_TIER.shp"
mngeo2 <- read_shape(file=mnshape)
str(mngeo2@data)
```

'data.frame':   683 obs. of  13 variables:
 $ MUNID     : int  1002 1002 1002 1009 1009 1009 1016 1016 1016 1026 ...
 $ MAH_CODE  : int  71616 71616 71616 71618 71618 71618 71614 71614 71614 71613 ...
 $ SGC_CODE  : int  1005 1005 1005 1011 1011 1011 1020 1020 1020 1030 ...
 $ ASSESSMENT: int  101 101 101 406 406 406 506 506 506 511 ...
 $ LEGAL_NAME: Factor w/ 414 levels "CITY OF BARRIE",..: 369 369 369 370 370 370 96 96 96 334 ...
 $ STATUS    : Factor w/ 2 levels "LOWER TIER","SINGLE TIER": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ EXTENT    : Factor w/ 3 levels "ISLANDS","LAND",..: 1 2 3 1 2 3 1 2 3 2 ...
 $ MSO       : Factor w/ 4 levels "CENTRAL","EASTERN",..: 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
 $ NAME_PREFI: Factor w/ 8 levels "-","CITY OF",..: 6 6 6 6 6 6 4 4 4 6 ...
 $ UPPER_TIER: Factor w/ 30 levels "BRUCE","DUFFERIN",..: 27 27 27 27 27 27 27 27 27 27 ...
 $ NAME      : Factor w/ 413 levels "ADDINGTON HIGHLANDS",..: 339 339 339 342 342 342 337 337 337 259 ...
 $ Shape_Leng: num  0.115 1.622 1.563 0.551 1.499 ...
 $ Shape_Area: num  2.32e-05 6.95e-02 7.51e-03 5.63e-04 5.09e-02 ...

```
mnmap <- append_data(mngeo2, Pop2014, key.shp = "MUNID", key.data="MUNID")
minPct <- min(c(mnmap@data$Population))
maxPct <- max(c(mnmap@data$Population))
paletteLayers <- colorBin(palette = "RdBu", domain = c(minPct, maxPct), bins = c(0, 50000,200000 ,500000, 1000000, 2000000) , pretty=FALSE)
rm(mngeo2)
rm(Pop2014)
rm(mnshape)
rm(datafile)
rm(maxPct)
rm(minPct)
gc()
leaflet(mnmap) %>%
  addProviderTiles("CartoDB.Positron") %>%
  addPolygons(stroke=TRUE, 
              smoothFactor = 0.2,
              weight = 1,
              fillOpacity = .6)
```

**Error: cannot allocate vector of size 177.2 Mb**

Is there I can maybe safe space through simplfying the shape file. If so how would I go about  doing this efficiently?

THanks

Comment: I suggest including what you have tried so far while attempting to fix the error, also I'd try to avoid dumping large walls of text in the post unless all of it is absolutely necessary.

Comment: Welcome to SO! If you encountered this issue while using R, you should at least add this language in your question tags.